# Estimation of Sum

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-numbers, summation

Given,

$2(1-|z|^2)^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+3)}\bigg(\frac{2(n+1)}{2n+3}+ (a+b)\bigg) |z|^{2n}+ab$

This question is a part of my research. I need to show that for what values of $a,b\in(-1,-\frac{2}{3})$ the above sum is positive where $0<|z|<1$.

I figure out the sum is positive for all values for which $a=b$ and $a,b \in \bigg ( \frac{-2(n+1)}{2n+3},\frac{-2(n+2)}{2n+5}\bigg )$ for any $n$. Is there any other $a,b\in (-1,-\frac{2}{3})$ s.t the sum is positive?

Any kind of help will be appreciated lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2(1-|z|^2)^2
\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} 
\frac{(n+1)^2}{(2n+3)}
\bigg(\frac{2(n+1)}{2n+3}+ (a+b)\bigg) 
|z|^{2n}+ab
$

When I see something like this,
I ask Wolfy.
For the first part,
I got,
with a fair amount of editing
and the result still 
looking wrong,

$\sum_{n=0}^m (x^{2 n} (n+1)^2)/(2 n+3) 
= -\dfrac{(x^9 (x^2)^m Φ(x^2, 1, m+5/2)
-2 x^7 (x^2)^m Φ(x^2, 1, m+5/2)
+x^5 (x^2)^m Φ(x^2, 1, m+5/2)
-2 x^7 (x^2)^m-4 m x^7 (x^2)^m+6 x^5 (x^2)^m
+4 m x^5 (x^2)^m
-2 x^4 \tanh^{-1}(x)
-6 x^3+4 x^2 \tanh^{-1}(x)
+2 x-2 \tanh^{-1}(x))}{(8 x^3 (x^2-1)^2)}
$

Letting $m \to \infty$,
so $x^{2m} \to 0$,
this becomes

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x^{2 n} (n+1)^2)/(2 n+3) 
&= -\dfrac{
-2 x^4 \tanh^{-1}(x)
-6 x^3+4 x^2 \tanh^{-1}(x)
+2 x-2 \tanh^{-1}(x)}{(8 x^3 (x^2-1)^2)}\\
&= -\dfrac{
\tanh^{-1}(x)(-2 x^4 +4 x^2-2)
-6 x^3 
+2 x)}{(8 x^3 (x^2-1)^2)}\\
&= -\dfrac{
\tanh^{-1}(x)(-2 x^4 +4 x^2-2)
)}{(8 x^3 (x^2-1)^2)}
+\dfrac{6 x^3-2 x}{(8 x^3 (x^2-1)^2)}\\
&= 2\dfrac{
\tanh^{-1}(x)( x^4 -2 x^2+1)
}
{(8 x^3 (x^2-1)^2)}
+\dfrac{3x^2-1}{(4 x^2 (x^2-1)^2)}\\
&= 2\dfrac{
\tanh^{-1}(x)( x^2-1)^2
}
{(8 x^3 (x^2-1)^2)}
+\dfrac{3x^2-1}{(4 x^2 (x^2-1)^2)}\\
\end{array}
$

There is a good chance that
I have made some error(s) here,
but the result should look
something like this.

Similarly,
entering
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x^{2 n} (n+1)^3)/(2 n+3)^2 
$
and letting the
upper limit go to $\infty$,
we get

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x^{2 n} (n+1)^3)/(2 n+3)^2 
&= -\dfrac{(4 x^7-4 x^5-20 x^3+24 x^2 \tanh^{-1}(x)+12 x-12x^{4}\tanh^{-1}(x)
-12 \tanh^{-1}(x))}{(32 x^3 (x^2-1)^2)}\\
&= -\dfrac{\tanh^{-1}(x)(12x^4+24 x^2 -12)+(4 x^7-4 x^5-20 x^3+12 x
)}{(32 x^3 (x^2-1)^2)}\\
\end{array}
$

At this point,
I'll stop
and let you
deal with these.

Note:
These results were gotten
by copying Wolfy's plaintext results
and doing a fair amount of editing
to make them
acceptable MathJax.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Actually what is Wolfy's plaintext ? It seems at $x=0$ sum is infinity which is not true I think.

Comment: I think the two sums cancel each out at zero, with one about $1/4x^2$ and the other being the negative of that.

Comment: At $x=0$ I am supposed to get $\frac{4}{9}+\frac{2a}{3}+\frac{2b}{3}+ab$ but when I add two sum and plug $x=0$ it makes infinity because I am not able to vanish $x$ in denominator. I am trying since yesterday but I didn't get that. Could you please do little bit further that satisfies the value at $x=0$.

Comment: Next thing we have $a+b$ in first sum then how could we combine those two and cancel the terms. I am really messed up.